# cargar datos mysql en select multiple php

Tags: php, mysql, select

necesito cargar en un select multiple, datos que vienen de mi base de datos mysql para poder eliminarlos si es necesario.

actualmente, tengo un array los ids de los datos a mostrar, se llama

```
$tareas = array('colado','encerado','enfilado');
```

aqui muestro el select multiple:

```
$prod = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM procesos WHERE id_cl = '$id_us' AND estado = 'S' ");

if ($prod->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<select name='procesos[]' id='multi' style='width: 100%;' class='select2 select2-multiple' multiple='multiple' data-placeholder='SELECCIONE TAREAS' >";
while ($row = $prod->fetch_array()) {                   
echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.strtoupper(utf8_encode($row['nombre'])).'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
}
```

mi idea es mostrar como seleccionados los que vienen del array ($tareas) y que no se muestren en la lista de datos que vienen de la consulta sql.
Alguna idea de como hacerlo?
como siempre agradecido de cualquier ayuda u orientacion que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Quieres que solo se muestre lo que esta en el array, o que lo esta en la base de datos se muestre, pero quite lo que esta en el array?

Comment: los datos que tiene el array vienen de algún lugar o son datos en duro?

Comment: @Oswaldo hola, exactamente. necesito que se muestren los que estan en el array pero los quite de la lista que viene de la BD. Obviamente al quitar uno que este en el array, que lo muestre en la lista que viene de la BD.

Comment: @KevinDelva ese array lo puse como muestra. los datos que contiene ese array, viene de otra consulta sql previa. saludos

Comment: Que tal si en la query `$prod` le agregas `AND campo IN ($consultaAnterior)`, te ahorrarías un poco de código

Comment: No es óptimo traer datos en la consulta para luego desecharlos. ¿Por qué motivo no filtras los datos en la misma consulta? Cuando haya millones de registros estarás trayendo millones de registros para luego aplicar filtros sobre ellos, sobrecargando el sistema. Es una pésima práctica, más aún sabiendo que las bases de datos tienen potentes herramientas de filtro de todo tipo.

Comment: @A.Cedano hola. si claro, tengo super claro que traer datos para luego desecharlos no es optimo. el motivo por el cual llamo a todos los datos de esta tabla (que son 5), es porque los ocupo todos. puse la consulta SELECT * para acotar un poco la pregunta y no sea tan engorroso el entendimiento de la misma. Saludos y gracias por tu acotacion.

Comment: Si necesitas todos los datos no se diga más, entonces es claro que debes traerlos todos. Pero todavía señalo algo, si vas a necesitar los datos en otros contextos es mejor volcar el conjunto de resultados en una variable, liberar los recursos de la BD y luego usar esa variable. Cuando los datos se van a usar en diferentes partes no es óptimo estarlos leyendo *in situ*, sino que habría que guardarlos: `while ($row = $prod->fetch_array()) { //no usar $row, almacenarlo en una variable }`

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por tu comentario. sin duda ayuda mucho a la forma en como puedo ir procesando la diferente informacion que vaya necesitando. lo aplicare como indicas. Se agradece como siempre tu interes y colaboracion. saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta utilizando los operadores `?:` con la función `in_array` para checar si existe marcarlo como seleccionado

Ejemplo:

```
 $prod = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM procesos WHERE id_cl = '$id_us' AND estado = 'S' ");
 if ($prod->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<select name='procesos[]' id='multi' style='width: 100%;' class='select2 select2-multiple' multiple='multiple' data-placeholder='SELECCIONE TAREAS' >";
    while ($row = $prod->fetch_array()) {                   
       echo '<option '.((in_array(strtolower(utf8_encode($row['id'])), $tareas))?"selected":"").' value="'.$row['id'].'">'.strtoupper(utf8_encode($row['nombre'])).'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
 }
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias estimado. era lo que necesitaba. hice una modificacion, ya que se debe comparar en in_array el id y no el nombre, pero funciono perfecto.